# Can I develop production code with Microsoft Parallel Extensions to .NET Framework 3.5, June 2008 Community Technology Preview?

Tags: .net, parallel-extensions

Is there any recommendation against using this CTP? Is it unstable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the download page:

> Note: This CTP is for testing purposes
>   only. Features and functionality may
>   change before final release, and
>   Microsoft may choose not to provide a
>   final release.

Also, in the EULA.rtf:

> 2. TERM.  The term of this agreement is until 1 January 2009, or commercial
>      release of the software, whichever is
>      first.

So actually it has **expired** and you are not licensed to use it. And even if it hadn't:

> - You may install and use any number
>     of copies of the software on your
>     premises to design, develop and test
>     your programs for use with the
>     software.
> - You may not test the
>     software in a live operating
>     environment unless Microsoft permits
>     you to do so under another agreement.

So no, you can not use it in a production environment without violating the license.

Answer (score 2):

I would say, it depends on what you would like to use it for, and when you will be shipping or delivering.

You certainly can take the bits now and develop against it. But be aware, that the API might change between now and the final release; which would mean that you have to change your code if you want to "upgrade" to the final version. Also, obviously there could be bugs in it, since it is a CTP.

As I see it, you should not use it if you are programming a space shuttle navigation system. On the other hand, if you are doing an in-house internal project that is not mission critical, it is propably fine to use.

You should decide whether you can bear the risk - against the new possibilities it gives you.

EDIT: As pointed out by Marc Gravell, the EULA says you can't use it in production. So the short answer is no, you are not allowed to use it for production software.

Comment: The EULA makes it clear that you can't legitimately use it in production. Or, in fact, at all (since it has expired).

Answer (score 1):

I'm using it in production right now, it works great. **BUT you have to test everything very thoroughly**, and everyone knows it's quite complicated to test multithreaded code.

I have run into the deadlocks issues that are mentioned somewhere in the "known issues" section of the docs. Not funny. In those cases I had to drop the extensions and everything went back to normal.

Comment: Note you are violating the license unless you have a separate agreement ;-p

Comment: Hopefully another CTP will be released soon :-)